# C# WPF Multiple Panels in App - how to do that

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm pretty new to WPF/XAML in C#, I saw some simple tutorials and stuff but, today I'm confused, never used to make UI there.

I need to output multiple forms which instance would look something like that:
[image]

(NB: I constructed it just in WYSIWG way, so XAML markup is total mess, it for screenshot. I cant even add table directly in grid, oh)

I got data like this for each month in schoolyear, so, depends on what class is choosen I want it to output like that (scheme)

(NB: instead of each `CustomWindowInstance` there I need my form from 1 st screenshot)

[image]

So, whats is best and simplies approach for that?

Comment: Are you using C# in macos?

Comment: @JoseAviles nope, its just screenshot from some online mockup constructor I made as fast as I could :)  I use Windows 10

Comment: @JoseAviles oh, online tool is here https://creately.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 1:** I'll name XAML from the first screenshot, which represents controls you want to display multiple times, XAML 1, and another one, where you want to do it, XAML 2.

--

*Almost* **ORIGINAL:**
Create a separate User Control and move the content of `Window` tag from XAML 1 into it. Then you'll be able to show it as many times as you want by placing `<yourUserControlNamespace:YourUserControlClass />` in XAML 2.

For an ability of communication with this control in XAML like `<yourUserControlNamespace:YourUserControlClass Parameter="SomethingHere" />` you should implement a [dependency property](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) with name `ParameterProperty` (desired name of property in XAML + "Property") in `YourUserControlClass.xaml.cs`.

--

**EDIT 2:** One may also create a [DataTemplate](https://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html) with parameter `DataType={x:Type yourVMNamespace:YourVMClass}` for the XAML 1's ViewModel (not View) in XAML 2's or the whole application's `Resources`. In that case the ViewModel class you are binding to will be represented by the `DataTemplate`'s content itself. Later you can write `<yourVMNamespace:YourVMClass />` as in the first solution.

This approach allows displaying rich representation of any items themselves, for example, in controls derived from `ItemsControl`, such as `ListBox`, all you've got to do is to bind `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` property to a collection of `YourVMClass` instances (or specify them in XAML by hand).

More precisely, in this case I won't call `YourVMClass` a ViewModel.